# Why the 'request' key is not in the binding's array in the container when I dd(app())

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade, laravel-service-container

To my understanding, the 'request' key returned by the `getFacadeAccessor method` in the Request Facade, refers to the key bound in the service container in the bindings array.

And when I dd(app('request')) I get the Request object. However, when I dd(app()) I don't see the 'request' key in the bindings array. Why is this so?